# Issues with StoryBoard ViewControllers in a Tabbed IOS App

Tags: ios, swift, tabbarcontroller

In the struggle of developing a Tabbed IOS App with Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3 based on MVC, I'm using the visual Storyboard elements instead of to do it programatically because I'm not an experienced developer. In the image attached below you can see the Architecture in the `StoryBoard` of the App:

[image: StoryBoard Architecture]

The App consists in:

- One `TabBarController` with four `TabBar Items`.
- Each `Item` has its own `ViewController` in `Storyboard`.
- All of them are linked with the `relationship seque`(ViewControllers) in `StoryBoard`.
- Each `ViewController` in the `StoryBoard` has its own `Class`.
- The last Item has an embedded `NavigationController` because I'm using a PageMenu project https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu to include a paging menu controller with a two child `ViewControllers`

The **Issues** I'm having until this point are:

1. The two `child ViewControllers` are not linked with the Last `TabBar Item` in the `StoryBoard`,as you can see in the figure above, only are instantiated in the `parent ViewController Class`(PageMenuViewController1), normally this `PageMenu` works but sometimes the last `TabBar Item` dissapears, **I'm very confused with this issue**.
2. The `override func viewWillAppear` into the default `child ViewController` is called twice at the first time, I've include a println("ClubsController viewWillAppear").

The code of the ViewControllers is

```js
import UIKit


class ClubsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

  @IBOutlet var tableview:UITableView!

  let apiClient = ApiClient()

  var clubs: [Club]!

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    println("ClubsController viewWillAppear")

    apiClient.clubsService.getList() { clubs, error in
      if clubs != nil {
        self.clubs = clubs
        self.tableview?.reloadData()
      }
      else {
        println("error: \(error)")
      }
    }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.clubs?.count ?? 0
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("clubObjectCell") as! ClubTableViewCell
    cell.clubObject = self.clubs?[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }

}
```

The code of the PageMenuViewController is

```js
import UIKit

class PageMenuViewController1: UIViewController {

  var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    println("PageMenuViewController1 viewWillAppear")

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    // Array to keep track of controllers in page menu
    var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

    // Create variables for all view controllers you want to put in the
    // page menu, initialize them, and add each to the controller array.
    // (Can be any UIViewController subclass)
    // Make sure the title property of all view controllers is set
    // Example:
    var controller1 = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ClubsViewController")! as! ClubsViewController
    controller1.title = "CLUBS"
    controllerArray.append(controller1)
    var controller2 = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PartiesViewController")! as! PartiesViewController
    controller2.title = "PARTIES"
    controllerArray.append(controller2)

    // Customize page menu to your liking (optional) or use default settings by sending nil for 'options' in the init
    // Example:
    var parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
      .MenuItemSeparatorWidth(4.3),
      .UseMenuLikeSegmentedControl(true),
      .MenuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight(0.1)
    ]

    // Initialize page menu with controller array, frame, and optional parameters
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    // Lastly add page menu as subview of base view controller view
    // or use pageMenu controller in you view hierachy as desired
    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
  }
}
```

Appreciate help to accomplish the best practices until this point.

Comment: Can you describe your problem more simply? Like "ViewController number 4 is not showing up in the UITabBar." Or what do you even want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not familiar with the CAPSPageMenu but there is nothing wrong with having scenes in a storyboard that aren't connected with a segue - this is just a convenience to help with transitions, and instantiating them with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is totally legitimate.

Something that does stand out looking at your storyboard is the way your table view controller with the navigation view controller is wired up.

The *navigation viewcontroller* should have the relationship with the tab bar controller - not the *table viewcontroller*.

Here's a screenshot of how the connection should look. Possibly this is why you're sometimes loosing a tab.

[image: Storyboard layout for tabs with a navigation controller]